# PHP Header already sent when variable is removed from command line

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, variables, header

So I have come to a veeeery weird thing about php logic.

I have made an htacces file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gameplay/

RewriteRule ^((?!forums|bans|stats)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^((?!forums|bans|stats)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

This makes sure that it converts all the strings in the first slashes in to php "p" variable, unless it is forums, bans or stats.

Weird part comes in when i try visiting the page.

Lets say that the url is `http://domain.com/gameplay/news/`
Everything is messed up, code shouts that header is sent there, there and everywhere else etc.

After I add a variable like this: `http://domain.com/gameplay/news/?x=x` or pretty much anything else, then it is completely fine and everything executes as it should...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure the PHP page is encoded in UTF-8 **without BOM**.

Make sure there are no empty spaces before the first tag of the document. Also check for `var_dump()` that could have been left over and could echo content before the first header in the php page

Comment: Then it wouldnt work even when i add the variable, but still it is without bom...